# How I can sum all numbers in array and print them as integer value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

enter code hereI have this number "811218-3476"as string,I want to multiply 8 by 2,1 by 1, 1 by2, 2 by1 and so on as following:

8 1 1 2 1 8 3 4 7 6

2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1  *

---

**16 1 2 2 2 8 6 4 14 7** ----> Result

My question is how I kan do sum for the result, I did sum one number with another number like

**16 + 1+2+2+2+8+6+4+14+7 = 62**,

but I want to do sum as following:

**1+6+1+2+2+2+8+6+4+1+4+7 = 47.**

I do not need you to write a code I have wrote it, but I want to know how I kan sum 1+6 instead of 16 as example. my code is here and it works fine.
I hope help know.

Thanks.

```
enter code here

 public static boolean checknumber(String s) {
 if(checkPersonNummer(s)== true) {
    char [] charray = s.toCharArray();
    int newch = 0 ;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
  String sum= "";
    
    int x = 0;
    
        for( j = 2; j < 8 ; j++) {
        System.out.print(" "+ charray[j] + "  ");}
        for( j = 9; j < charray.length ; j++) {
            System.out.print(" "+ charray[j] + "  ");}
         System.out.println("  ");
        for( j = 2; j < 8 ; j++) {
        if(j%2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" "+ 2 +  "  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" "+ 1 +  "  ");
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("  ");
            for( j = 9; j < charray.length; j++) {
            if(j%2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(" "+ 2 +  "  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" "+ 1 +  "  ");
                }
            }
        System.out.print("\n--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        
        for( i = 2;i < 8;i++) {
        if(i% 2 == 0) {
            newch = Character.getNumericValue(charray[i] )* 2;
            sum  += newch;
            
            }
        else {
            newch = Character.getNumericValue(charray[i]) * 1;
            sum  += newch;
            
        }
        
        System.out.print(newch + "   " );
        
    }
        for( i = 9;i < charray.length;i++) {
            if(i% 2 == 0) {
                newch = Character.getNumericValue(charray[i] )* 1;
                sum  += newch;
                
                }
            else {
                newch = Character.getNumericValue(charray[i]) * 2;
                sum += newch;
            
            }
            
            System.out.print(newch + "   " );
        }   
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Total = " + sum);
    }   
        
return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Yes! I edit my question to show my code,I can do sum of numbers but I want to sum 1+6 instead of 16.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a homework assignment, and we're not a homework writing team. But I'll give you some basic advice.

First, I had one person tell me, "programming is the art of editing the null program until it does what you want". By that he meant that we start with a program that does nothing and slowly built it up.

That's a good way to start.

So... Start your program. You need to get your data in. Do that, and figure out how to print it.

After that, think about printing out each number times either 1 or 2 as your problem requires, and print each calculation as you go.

Then all you have to do is keep a variable outside of this loop to store the sum, and add each mini-calculation to it, then print it at the end.

Start small. Work up to the final answer. Lots of debug output while working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I have an array of numbers `[2,3,4,5,6]`, Think of this question as you are multiplying the numbers with 1 those are at odd position in the array and multiplying the numbers with 2 those are at even position in the array.

**Answer to `How to add 1 + 6 instead of 16`**

- Check if the number is less than 10, if it is than you don't have to
  worry about it But,
- If the number is greater than 10 you can use the % operator.

**For instance**
`15 % 10` gives you 5 and `15 / 10` gives you 1 that way you can separate two individual digits.